# fix column number in R

Tags: r

I have another problem with read.table. The fill option says "in case the rows have unequal length, blank fields are implicitly added." The problem is that the blank fields do not prevent R from forgetting that field. e.g. I have two lines, each with 4 columns, but in the second line one of the columns is empty. I want to read table this and insert a zero so that the number of colums stays fixed. Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The file looks like this:

```
A B C
0 0 1
0 1
1 1 0
0
```

You read it in R:

```
content <- read.table("file.txt", header=T, fill=NA)
```

And get:

```
  A  B  C
1 0  0  1
2 0  1 NA
3 1  1  0
4 0 NA NA
```